# How do I enable auto-complete for a git-flow alias?

Tags: git, bash, autocomplete, alias, git-flow

This is breaking

```
alias f='git flow feature'
complete -F __git_flow_feature f
```

It works eventually (after 2 'tabs') but throws an error on each 'tab' press.

```
-bash: [: 1: unary operator expected
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running macOS? try this: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/f710a1395f44224e4bcc3518ee9c13a0dc850be1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me, when I do:

1. wget http://www.triquanta.nl/sites/default/files/git-flow.bash
2. source git-flow.bash
3. alias f='git flow feature'
4. complete -F __git_flow_feature f
5. f <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>

Anyhow, the most common reason for the *"[: 1: unary operator expected"* error is that you have in the shell script code like:

```
if [ 1 = $MYVAL ]
```

and your `MYVAL` is not set. Inspect your completion functions. You can add `set -x` to debug it.

Usually the easiest solution is to quote the variable so the operator will get the empty argument, but will have correct number of arguments:

```
if [ 1 = "$MYVAL" ]
```

Comment: Since it's bash, use `[[` instead of `[`. It's much smarter

Answer (score 3):

Why don't just use [git-flow-completion](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion)? The instructions for *bash* are:

```
$ cd /etc/bash_completion.d
$ sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/master/git-flow-completion.bash
$ exec $SHELL
```

there are also instructions for [zsh](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion#installation-for-zsh) or [fish](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion#installation-for-fish).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too and every Google search lead me back to this post.

I am posting the solution I found using Michal's answer and Daenyth's comment...

My git-flow.bash was identical, but I think our git completion files might be varying.

To fix this I had to modify my git completion file located at `/etc/bash_completion.d/git`

Old:

```
# __git_find_on_cmdline requires 1 argument
__git_find_on_cmdline ()
{
local word subcommand c=1
while [ $c -lt $cword ]; do
    word="${words[c]}"
    for subcommand in $1; do
        if [ "$subcommand" = "$word" ]; then
            echo "$subcommand"
            return
        fi
    done
    c=$((++c))
done
}
```

New:

```
# __git_find_on_cmdline requires 1 argument
__git_find_on_cmdline ()
{
local word subcommand c=1
while [[ $c -lt $cword ]]; do
    word="${words[c]}"
    for subcommand in $1; do
        if [ "$subcommand" = "$word" ]; then
            echo "$subcommand"
            return
        fi
    done
    c=$((++c))
done
}
```

Notice the double bracket I had to add to the new code.  That was the only change I made.

Comment: have not worked for me, still with the same error [: 1: unary operator expected

Answer (score 1):

I have this aliases:

```
alias gn="git-number"
alias gb="gn -c git blame"
alias ge="gn -c $EDITOR"
alias ga="gn add"
alias gr="gn -c git reset"
alias gap="EDITOR='$EDITOR -w' gn add -p"
alias gd="gn -c git diff -b -w --ignore-blank-lines"
alias gds="gd --staged"
alias gc="gn -c git checkout"
alias gcf="git flow feature checkout"
alias gl="gn -c git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines"
alias gls="git log --stat"
alias cm="EDITOR='$EDITOR -w' git commit"
alias grb="git stash save 'REBASE' && EDITOR='$EDITOR -w' git rebase -i"
alias grbc="EDITOR='$EDITOR -w' git rebase --continue"

gcd() {
    test -n "$1" && cd $(dirname $(git list $1))
}

source ~/.git-completion.bash
__git_complete gn  _git
__git_complete ga  _git_add
__git_complete gap _git_add
__git_complete gd  _git_diff
__git_complete gds _git_diff
__git_complete gc  _git_checkout
__git_complete gcf _git_checkout
__git_complete gl  _git_log
__git_complete gls _git_log
__git_complete cm  _git_commit

source ~/.git-flow-completion.bash
```

And install `completion` scripts as:

```
wget -O ~/.git-completion.bash https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
wget -O ~/.git-flow-completion.bash https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petervanderdoes/git-flow-completion/develop/git-flow-completion.bash
```

Git number noted here is: https://github.com/holygeek/git-number
Just copy binaries at repo to `~/bin`